# How to add SSR in angular 16?

Tags: angular

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQHV7.png)

```
npm ERR! Missing script: "prerender"
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@abacritt/angularx-social-login": "^2.1.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^15.2.10",
    "@angular/router": "^16.2.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^15.1.2",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^16.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "canvas-confetti": "^1.9.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "html2canvas": "^1.4.1",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^12.0.2",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^7.1.2",
    "ngx-toastr": "^17.0.2",
    "page-flip": "^2.0.7",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.2.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^16.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.2.0",
    "@types/canvas-confetti": "^1.6.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "@types/page-flip": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.7",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.1.3"
  }
```